# Is it good to put a &nbsp; inside an empty <td>?

Tags: html, w3c, semantic-markup

If this is the structure:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <tr>
      <td>I don't need anything here, should I always put a &nbsp; here?</td>
      <td>item </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>model</td>
      <td>one</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>model</td>
      <td>two</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>model</td>
      <td>three</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

How will a screen reader read a blank `td`? Is it semantically correct?

Answer (score 18):

Semantically correct IMHO would be to keep an empty cell *really* empty. However, I, too, fill empty cells with `&nbsp;`s for pragmatic reasons.

As for screen readers, I'll have to make an educated guess: Empty nodes will likely not be read, because HTML consists mostly of whitespace text nodes, which readers ignore, and I assume, that `&nbsp;` is collapsed to a simple space in *reader applications* (since *non-breaking* is a property of visual media).

For rendering visually, one could rely on the CSS table property [`empty-cells`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#empty-cells):

```
table {
    empty-cells: show;
}
```

Comment: I think this property is not supported in IE

Comment: That's true, and the reason, why I still use `&nbsp;`s, unfortunately.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/empty-cells), the `empty-cells` property has support in IE 8.

Comment: Ah, you see, young padawan, back in those days of 2010, IE 7 still was a thing ;-) But yes, nowadays `empty-cells` is the way to go regardless.

Comment: Three years later there are apparently half a billion people still using OE, which is IE7, so email generally still has to comply with IE7.

Answer (score 6):

Semantically, an HTML table is really just an array (matrix) of data, and there’s no reason why a no-break space character could not be treated as data. Whether it really makes sense depends on the purpose, structure, and content of the table. In most cases, there is a better solution. See some suggestion in [Empty cells in HTML tables](http://jkorpela.fi/HTML/emptycells.html).

On the technical side, the no-break space has width and height, depending on the font, and this imposes minimum requirements on the dimensions of the cell. This may matter, though mostly in cases where the row or the column is used just as a separator, e.g. to create horizontal or vertical line.

Another impact of using a no-break space, as opposite to using a normal space or leaving the cell completely empty, is that it may affect the appearance of borders around the cell and background color and background image inside the cell.

Screen readers differ in the way they indicate empty cells, if at all, and this may also depend on the reading mode. In any case, the user gets no indication of what’s really going on, i.e. what an empty cell (if the emptiness is conveyed to the user at all) means. In visual browsing, the meaning may (or may not) be rather obvious.

Comment: I fixed the link.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to editors like Dreamweaver this practice became somewhat of a standard, so even if it is not a perfect solution - at least you won't be alone in doing it. Plus it is more compatible with older browser than CSS's `empty-cells`.

Answer (score 0):

there isn't anything exactly saying you shouldn't use use a blank TD, and it passes when you try to validate.

Although, a more elegant approach would be to use colspan.

i.e.

```
<tr>
   <td colspan="2">item </td>
</tr>
```

But this will align your content to the left, and you will have to manually (via css) apply styles so the content is aligned where you want.

The good thing about using it with colspans, is that screen readers will read only what's there, and not the empty spaces

Comment: The `colspan` is not necessary more elegant or semantic. `colspan` says effectively, that the value of the table cell is a valid combination of values that usually would belong in two different cells. In the above case: If the first row is a heading, then `colspan` gives a completely wrong result (i.e., the cell content is marked up as label for *both* columns).