# Skip <td> in HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

Say I have the following table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Example</td>
    </td>One</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Example</td>
    </td>Two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Example</td>
    </td>Three</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <!--
    Here I want to skip the first <td> cell; use only second. Example:
    <td>(empty, possibly &nbsp;)</td>
    <td>blah blah blah</td>
    -->
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you read my comment in the last row, you can see that in the last row I want to display something in the second column of the table, with the first remaining empty. How would I go about doing this?

As a side note, I read the question/answers in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506342/is-it-good-to-put-a-nbsp-inside-an-empty-td) but colspan is different from what I want. I'm also not familiar with css `empty-cell` so if that is a solution, please provide a bit of sample code.

Comment: Have you tried your own suggestions? There's no reason `<td></td>` or `<td>&nbsp;</td>` shouldn't work unless you've already tried this and are not getting the desired result.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it good to put a &nbsp; inside an empty <td>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506342/is-it-good-to-put-a-nbsp-inside-an-empty-td)

Comment: As you note, the question is a duplicate. It is better to improve answers to existing questions than to spawn duplicates. Explaining the real purpose and content may help in getting better answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HTML

```
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>content here</td>
</tr>
```

CSS

`table { empty-cells: show;}`

Leave the `<td>` empty, no reason to put a space in there. `&nbsp;` can act a bit funny at times, especially in tables.

Answer (score 8):

I can't see any reason not to do exactly what you are proposing: Use an empty cell containing only a `&nbsp;` ("*No Break Space*") in it:

```
<tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>Whatever</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: is it safe to omit `<td>` alltogether and write content directly to tr ?

Comment: Hi! Fun to receive a question to a 8 years old post! :)  Now to answer your question: I don't think you should do that. A `<tr>` (table row) should not contain visible content directly. Seems it can contain `<th>`, `<td>` as well as `<script>` and `<template>` tags - see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr#Technical_summary

Comment: thanks man, $nbsp; help me to get rid of wrapping background color of last column to first column of next row)

Answer (score 3):

CSS code:

```css
table { empty-cells: show; }
```

Or, alternatively, you can insert `&nbsp;` in the `<td>`.