# HTML Table customizing issue

Tags: html, html-table

I'm building my website and now I'm facing a small problem:

I'd like to cut `**(This one)**` cell from the table, but I need to stick the last  in it's position (because when i delete the third `<td>` the last one moves to it's position).

Can anyone suggest what to do? Sorry, I'm only a beginner, maybe there's duplicate thread somewhere.

(P.S: I'm building website's layout using tables, is it good choice or not?)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>**(This one)**</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Building websites with tables is a little bit outdated, but if you're beginner, it is okay.

Comment: try to use frameworks for web development. It is easier for beginners. You can try Twitter Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com. And using tables to develop modern websites is not advisable.

Comment: suggesting frameworks to people just getting started in web development is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: do you want a javascript pure solution? Can I use jquery?

Comment: I used to work with bootstrap, but I didn't like it, since I don't want to stick only to one design of elements ( I know there is custom templates, but all in all it's very similar) :D

Comment: @KasparasTaminskas just delete the content inside td .

Comment: @sush it won't help, since the space stays.

Comment: @KasparasTaminskas you didn't want the 4th cell to move to its space. and hence there is a space

Comment: @sush I do want to move another div to third element place. Anyway the answer was written below, thanks all!

Comment: No,I just want to move another div not from the table in to the third  one's place, it's just like cutting table and making it not correct form :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>**(This one)**</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table { empty-cells: show;}
```

Leave the  empty, no reason to put a space (`&nbsp;`) there.

and You should not be using the Table Design whereas use Tableless Design because The advantages of restricting the use of HTML tables to their intended and semantic purpose include improved accessibility of the information to a wider variety of users, using a wide variety of user agents. There are bandwidth savings as large numbers of semantically meaningless ,  and  tags are removed from dozens of pages leaving fewer, but more meaningful headings, paragraphs and lists. Layout instructions are transferred into site-wide CSS stylesheets, which can be downloaded once and cached for reuse while each visitor navigates the site. Sites may become more maintainable as the whole site can be restyled or re-branded in a single pass merely by altering the mark-up of the specific CSS, affecting every page which relies on that stylesheet. New HTML content can be added in such a way that consistent layout rules are immediately applied to it by the existing CSS without any further effort.

I am also a very big fan of Table Design but then I discover **What are the benefits of table less design?**

There are many, not the least of which is reduced HTML payload, and the flexibility to change the layout (via CSS) without changing the markup.

One way they reduce payload is that, with styles stored in an external stylesheet, and stylesheets often being shared between pages, caching really swings in to the rescue. One could argue that stylesheets can be used with tables. Yup; however, disciplined use of divs for layout tends to promote the use stylesheets.

You could read up on Search-Engine Optimisation (SEO) design. One principal of SEO is to get your important content up toward the top of the HTML tree, above relatively unimportant stuff like navigation. This really isn't possible with table-based design.

**What are the conditions when tables should be used?**

Use tables to show tabular data. Avoid them for layout.

**How to begin?**

I'm a fan of w3schools, and the awsome [CSS Zen Garden](http://csszengarden.com/). Those gave me my start.

Answer (score 2):

Please see [Skip <td> in HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640581/skip-td-in-html-table)

You should not use tables to do website layout.

Comment: Thanks! Could someone explain why should I avoid tables as the way of making layout?

Comment: dont avoid using tables, if you like them then use them. its just that there are better ways of achieving a good layout now, but table is still fine

Comment: The reason is semantics. Tables are intended for tabular data display. Divs, sections, headers, footers, etc are intended for layout. Sure, you could use a spoon to eat a steak, but people will tell you you're doing it wrong - if you don't mind, tell them to piss off. If you want to be accepted and invited over to dinner at a party, don't be the spoon-using-steak-eater guy.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking this?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>002</td>
</tr>
<tr>       
    <td colspan="2"> 004 </td>
</tr>
```