# Getting the parent node if there is no child node in XSLT

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Below is the input xml which i have

```
<InputAnimationConfigurationSchema>
  <ConfigurationEffects>
  <AEffect Id="1" DisplayName="A Effect">
  </WipeEffect>
  <BEffect Id="2" DisplayName="B Effect">
  </FadeEffect>
  <CEffect Id="3" DisplayName="C Effect">
</ConfigurationEffects>
<ConfigurationMappings>
 <ConfigurationMap>
   <Widget Type="All" Include="true" NeedsMandatoryEffectConfiguration="true"/>
   <Trigger Type="Show" />
   <ConfigurationEffects>
    <Effect>1</Effect>
    <Effect>2</Effect>
    <Effect>3</Effect>
    <Effect>9</Effect>
   </ConfigurationEffects>
 </ConfigurationMap>
 <ConfigurationMap>
   <Widget Type="All" Include="true" NeedsMandatoryEffectConfiguration="true"/>
   <Trigger Type="Hide" />
   <ConfigurationEffects>
    <Effect>1</Effect>
    <Effect>2</Effect>
    <Effect>3</Effect>
    <Effect>9</Effect>
   </ConfigurationEffects>
 </ConfigurationMap>
 <ConfigurationMap>
  <Widget Type="PIGWidget" Include="false" NeedsMandatoryEffectConfiguration="true"/>
 </ConfigurationMap>
 <ConfigurationMap>
  <Widget Type="PlaceHolder" Include="false" NeedsMandatoryEffectConfiguration="true"/>
 </ConfigurationMap>
  </ConfigurationMappings>
 </InputAnimationConfigurationSchema>
```

I was getting the output in the below format:

```
All        Show     A Effect
--------------------------
All        Show     C Effect
--------------------------
All        Show     F Effect
-------------------------
All        Show     I Effect
----------------------------
All        Hide     A Effect
---------------------------
All        Hide     C Effect
--------------------------
```

Now the problem i am facing is like if there is no child node available for the parent node then that node is not getting printed but i need to display the widget placeholder and pigwidget also

I want the output in the below format:

```
All        Show     A Effect
--------------------------
All        Show     C Effect
--------------------------
All        Show     F Effect
-------------------------
All        Show     I Effect
----------------------------
All        Hide     A Effect
---------------------------
All        Hide     C Effect
--------------------------
placeholder
---------------------------
pigwidget
---------------------------
```

for above the XSL i wrote is like:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
   <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="effectLookup"  match="/InputAnimationConfigurationSchema/ConfigurationEffects/*" use="@Id" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
     <html>
     <body>
        <h2></h2>
        <table border="1">
           <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
              <th>Widget</th>
              <th>Trigger</th>
              <th>effects</th>
           </tr>
           <xsl:for-each  select="/InputAnimationConfigurationSchema/ConfigurationMappings/ConfigurationMap">
              <xsl:variable name="widgetType">
                 <xsl:value-of select="Widget/@Type"/>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:variable name="triggerType">
                 <xsl:value-of select="Trigger/@Type"/>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:for-each select="ConfigurationEffects/Effect">
                 <xsl:variable name="effectId">
                    <xsl:value-of select="./text()"/>
                 </xsl:variable>
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                       <xsl:value-of select="$widgetType"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <xsl:value-of select="$triggerType"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <xsl:value-of select="key('effectLookup',   $effectId)/@DisplayName" />
                    </td>
                 </tr>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
     </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please guide me how to achieve the same?

Comment: @stuartLC--this one was your code which i copied..need little more help for displaying the parent node if there was no child node

Answer (score 0):

I've refactored the for loops into templates, and removed the redundant variables. 
Logic has been added to distinguish between `ConfigurationMaps` with and without `ConfigurationEffect` children.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="effectLookup"
           match="/InputAnimationConfigurationSchema/ConfigurationEffects/*" 
           use="@Id" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <h2></h2>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Widget</th>
            <th>Trigger</th>
            <th>effects</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates 
select="/InputAnimationConfigurationSchema/ConfigurationMappings/ConfigurationMap" />
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ConfigurationMap">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="not(ConfigurationEffects)">
        <xsl:call-template name="EmptyConfiguration">
          <xsl:with-param name="widgetType" select="Widget/@Type" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ConfigurationEffects/Effect" />
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Effect">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../Widget/@Type"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="../../Trigger/@Type"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('effectLookup', ./text())/@DisplayName" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="EmptyConfiguration">
    <xsl:param name="widgetType" />
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3">
        <xsl:value-of select="$widgetType"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2></h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
        <th>Widget</th>
        <th>Trigger</th>
        <th>effects</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>All</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>A Effect</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>All</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>B Effect</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>All</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>C Effect</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>All</td>
        <td>Show</td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>All</td>
        <td>Hide</td>
        <td>A Effect</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>All</td>
        <td>Hide</td>
        <td>B Effect</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>All</td>
        <td>Hide</td>
        <td>C Effect</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>All</td>
        <td>Hide</td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">PIGWidget</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="3">PlaceHolder</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that even after fixing your xml input, that there is no EffectId 9, hence the empty `td`.

Comment: @stuartLC--as because of this line                                           <td colspan="3">
 <xsl:value-of select="$widgetType"/>
</td> the widget is spanning in all the 3 columns,for all other columns border is getting overlaped..wanna know how to retain the other 2 columns with their border even if there is no data

Comment: Yes, that is basic Html. Remove the `colspan` attribute, and add in the 2 other `td`s back in. Watch for the empty `<td>` [rendering issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506342/is-it-good-to-put-a-nbsp-inside-an-empty-td)