# How to get a table-cell aligned to the right?

Tags: css, alignment, css-tables

I have a table with two rows.
Looks something like this:

```
—————————————————
|   1   |   2   |
|———————————————|
|   3   |       |
—————————————————
```

The first row has two cells, but the second has only one.

How can I get the only table-cell in the second row, to align under the the second table-cell in the first row? (without adding a cell before the cell in the second row)
Like this:

```
—————————————————
|   1   |   2   |
|———————————————|
|       |   3   |
—————————————————
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell one">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="cell two">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell three">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
div.table {
    display:table;
    background:#EEE;
    padding:10px;
}
 div.row {
    display:table-row;
    background:#610;
    padding:10px;
    width:100%;
    text-align:right;
}
 div.cell {
    display:table-cell;
    background:#016;
    padding:10px;
    color:white;
    font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7H7rf/).

I've tried margins & floats. I would like to avoid absolute and floats if possible though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the only reason you don't want an extra cell because you don't have control of the HTML, you could do this:

```
.row + .row:before {
    content: '';
    display:table-cell;
    background-color:white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7H7rf/6/

Answer (score 4):

Why not just add an empty cell? There is nothing wrong with this. See this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842218/whats-the-best-way-to-represent-an-empty-th-in-html5)

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/KV9GL/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell one">
            1
        </div>
        <div class="cell two">
            2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell three"></div>
        <div class="cell three">
            3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then use the following CSS to make the background of an empty cell gray:

```
div.cell:empty {
    background:#EEE;
}
```

Comment: I know the line doesn't stand out in the question, but it says I'd like to avoid that in the parenthesis.

Comment: @henryaaron Alright, I must have missed that, unless you just added that in... There is nothing wrong with an empty cell see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842218/whats-the-best-way-to-represent-an-empty-th-in-html5

Comment: Oh, I'm well aware of that. I don't have control over my HTML unfortunately........................

Comment: @henryaaron Nonetheless, this is the best solution to the problem regardless of whether *you* can edit the HTML or not. If you looked at the question I linked to, you will see that [BoltClock's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclocks-a-unicorn) answer points out that a **[W3 spec (example)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#examples)** used an empty table for the exact same purpose.

Answer (score 1):

i dont know what are you exactly trying to acheive but try this one

```
.three
{
position:relative!important;
left:100%!important;
display:inline-block!important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7H7rf/4/

well you can just rename the class to .right_cell

Comment: FF doesn't agree with this method.

Comment: Yes, according to the W3C spec, table elements shouldn't be positioned.

Comment: @m59 im solving an issue not desgning a standard

Comment: the best solution was to add empty cell , but @henryaaron said he doesnt want to !

Comment: @ProllyGeek I have no idea what  you're saying. Do you mean that we can just make up solutions that don't work and all the browsers should implement whatever we write?

Comment: @m59 no but im saying when you have a problem , and the client refuses the logical solution then you should come up with a " work around " , and my solution corresponds to all browsers !! anyway i was trying to help and it is up to the one who asked the question to tell if my answer was satisfying or not !! doesnt worth wasting time :)

Comment: @ProllyGeek *maybe* it works in all updated browsers. It seems that the most recent firefox version does support it.

Comment: _left: 100%_ was useful for me (hence +1), still it would be better not to suggest _!important_ up front, it should be used as a last resort when absolutely necessary.