# How to skip a cell in a table with HTML?

Tags: html

How do I skip the first cell of the first row with HTML, while maintaining the table border on the rest of the table (like the example in the picture)? I know how to do this with individual cell borders, but I want to keep the outside table border instead with no cell borders. Is there a way, for example, to begin the first row at the second column?

[image: Picture of table - example]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Please include the HTML that you want reviewed to help others answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Make an empty cell to represent the cutout (this [is valid and recommended by the spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842218/whats-the-best-way-to-represent-an-empty-th-in-html5/19842702#19842702)), remove the background from that empty cell, and give it the same border properties as the table, but set its border style to hidden where it overlaps the table's border (in this case, the top and left borders). Any of a table cell's borders whose style is hidden causes any borders that would overlap it in collapsed-borders mode to disappear ([CSS2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#border-conflict-resolution), [css-tables-3](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-tables-3/#border-specificity)):

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}

th {
  background-color: #56a9ce;
}

th, td {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

tr:first-child > th:first-child {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px #000;
  border-style: hidden solid solid hidden;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th><th colspan="3">Content</th>
    <tr>
      <th>Content</th><th>Content</th><th>Content</th><th>Content</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td>
    <tr>
      <td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td>
    <tr>
      <td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td><td>X</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I would have never thought you could overlap a solid border with a hidden one and not see it through.

Comment: @julien.giband: One of the hidden (heh) gems of table CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS pseudo-class is a keyword. For example, to begin the first row at the second column:

```
.table tr:first-child > td:ntn-child(2) {
  // Something
}
```

You can use `:not()` too.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set your borders per cell rather than globally on your table.

Code could look like

```css
table {
  border: none;
}
table tr:first-child td {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}
table tr:last-child td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

/* ... same for columns with pseudo classes on td */

/* first cell in first row */
table tr:first-child td:first-child {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left-color: transparent;
  border-top-color: transparent;
}
```

I'm letting you figure out the details by yourself